# Metric space containing distinct points $a$ and $b$ such that $N_R(a) \subset N_r(b)$ where $R > r > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Does such a metric space exist that satisfies this property?

Comment: The post office metric on the reals has examples of this phenomenon.

Comment: @pokerlegend23 Please do not vandalize posted questions, including your own. Rolled back.

Comment: ok sorry, it said [on hold] so I wasn't sure if it meant I should delete my post

Answer (score 1):

The discrete metric (all points have distance $1$) works: if $R>r\ge1$ then $N_R(a)$ and $N_r(b)$ are equal to the whole space.